# Can gray weekend coloring be eliminated on Calendar for Mavericks?

Tags: macos, calendar

I'm running OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks). The new calendar design has the weekends tinted gray.  Fine, I suppose, if you're a 9-5er, but I'm a musician and weekends are my weekdays.  Weeks aren't all the same, and any day can be a work day or a day off.

[image: Gray color for Saturday]

Does anyone know how to turn off the gray tint if I can't assign my weekends to match my actual schedule?

Comment: What happens if you change "Week Begins On..." to Friday?

Comment: It just moves the calendar to the side — doesn't change the shading of the days.

Answer (score 1):

No, this cannot be changed.

It is hard coded.

Comment: You cannot, there are no other options for color. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I checked all of the preference values stored in `com.apple.iCal.plist` and there's nothing that affects what days are gray, so I don't think this is possible even with a hidden setting.

A pragmatic approach might be to use a different calendar app to read the same data as Apple's calendar uses. Two of the best options for third party calendars are:

- http://www.busymac.com/busycal/
- https://flexibits.com/fantastical